# Plot multiple lines with colour and legends

Tags: plotting, legending, labeling

Function of interest:

```
f[n_, r_] := (1 - r^2)^((n - 4)/2)/(Beta[1/2, (n - 2)/2])
```

In separate graphs:

```
Table[  Plot[f[n, r], {r, -1, 1},   Frame -> True,   GridLines -> Automatic,   PlotLegends -> "Expressions"   ], {n, 4, 19}]
```

Now if I do

```
Plot[Table[f[n, r], {n, 4, 19}], {r, -1, 1},  Frame -> True,  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"  ]
```

[image]

This gives no Legends. Then I try

```
tmp = Table[f[n, r], {n, 4, 19}]
Plot[tmp, {r, -1, 1},  Frame -> True,  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"  ]
```

[image]
It works fine, but not exactly the legends I want. How can I have legends with specific values of `n` and `r`, like `f(8,r)`, or `f(4,r)`, or anything that is more informative?

```
Plot[tmp, {r, -1, 1},  Frame -> True,  PlotLegends -> Table["f(" <> ToString[n] <> ",r)", {n, 4, 19}]  ]
```

[image]

This is also ok, but is can I do it without introducing the exatra `tmp` variable? There must be a more efficient way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate @ Table[f[n, r], {n, 4, 19}], {r, -1, 1}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotLegends -> Table["f(" <> ToString[n] <> ",r)", {n, 4, 19}]]
```

[image]

You can also use

```
 PlotLegends -> Table[Inactivate @ f[n, r], {n, 4, 19}] (* or *)
 PlotLegends -> (TraditionalForm @ Defer@f[#, r] & /@ Range[4, 19])
```

to get the same result.